# javascript async fetch function

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch

I am trying to create a recursive function that sends a PUT request for every integer of a given array, and call another function at the end of it.

```
function fetchArchive(arr,state,mailbox){
  if(arr.length == 0){
    load_mailbox(mailbox)
  }
  for(i of arr){
    fetch(`/emails/${arr.shift()}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify({
          archived: state
      })
    })
    .then(fetchArchive(arr,state,mailbox))
  }
}
```

But it seems that it calls the `load_mailbox()` function before fetching the last item of the  array.
I know that this should be better implemented using `async / await`. Can someone give an example of that to help me understand?

UPDATE:
It turns out that the code below is working

```
async function fetchArchive(a,s,callback){
  for(i of a){
    await fetch(`/emails/${i}`, {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: JSON.stringify({
          archived: s
      })
    })
    // if i is the last item, load mailbox
    .then(() => { if(i==a[a.length-1] && callback) callback()});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct code for async for..of loop

```js
async function fetchArchive(arr,state,mailbox){
    console.log(1)
  if(arr.length === 0){
    load_mailbox(mailbox)
  }
    
  for await (const elem of arr){
    await fetch2(elem);
        arr.shift();

        console.log({ elem })

    fetchArchive(arr,state,mailbox)
  }
}
```

However, this code does not work and causes infinity recursion :)
I think it is bad idea to mutate the array inside iteration.
Also, please keep in mind, that `then` receives callback.
So, the propper argument for `then` is:

```js
.then(response=>fetchArchive(respone))
```

In your case, you can't pass `fetchArchive` as an argument to `then` method because `fetchArchive` does not return function

[UPDATE]

This is the working code with array index comparison:

```js
const fetchArchive = async (a, s, callback) => {
  for (const [index, value] of a.entries()) {
    await fetch(index)
      // if i is the last item, load mailbox
      .then(() => {
        if (index == a.length - 1 && callback) {
          callback();
        }
      });
  }
};
```

Documentation about `entries` U can find [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried with the async function I've just added at the end of the question. What do you think about it?

Comment: Much better now, however there is still one problem, here: i==a[a.length-1].
U are trying to compare value to value. The best way to know if it is the end of array is to compare array indexes. Indexes are always integers, when values could be anything. Please see update in my answer

Comment: Looks way better now, Thanks!!